# continously run a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am designing a web-page to allow users to edit geographical features on the fly.  I use a simple function to calculate road lengths that they have been created.  The issue is that I have to reload the page to update the statistics.  The function I use to create the statistics is below, how can I make this run to update the stat's without reloading the page:

```
function postExecute() {
    var roadLengthCalc = Math.round(RoadLength['RoadLength']);
    document.getElementById("Road_Length").innerHTML = roadLengthCalc;
}
```

Comment: why don't you just trigger this function after some user-side event happens?

Comment: There are several ways to get a real time web application, e.g., Comet, WebSockets, ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `setInterval` function:

For example:

```
setInterval(function(){ postExecute(); },3000);
```

The `3000` is the frequency in milliseconds.

**Documentation:**

You can find the full documentation for this function at the link below:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

**JSFiddle working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/d5DkA/